# Prove tha union of open intervals can be written as a union of disjoint open intervals

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Here is my proof.

Let U be an union of open sets and suppose x belongs to U.

Suppose there is largest open interval I that contains x.

Then Consider U-I, if this is empty, then we are done.

If U-I is not empty, pick any point y in U-I and let J be the largest open interval that contains y. In general, intersection of J and I must be empty, otherwise this would contradict our assumption.

If we keep doing this process, we would end up getting disjoint Union of open sets.

Is this rigorous proof?

Comment: It’s not rigorous: to make it so, you’d have to prove that for each $x\in U$ there *is* a largest open interval $I$ such that $x\in I\subseteq U$. Proving that is really the heart of the argument. That’s a pretty big hole that isn’t trivial to fix, so I’m going to close this as a duplicate: at the earlier question you'll find a variety of proofs.

Answer (score 1):

U is the disjoint union of its connected components. Each connected component of U is an interval whose interior is an interval since each element of U is contained in an interval.